# Outlook search fields not getting edited

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

In the search box in Outlook 2016 (Office 365 ver 1704 build 8067.2115), once I enter the search content it shows all relevant emails. However if I try to change any field content From/To or Subject or Body, nothing can be edited. I have to forcibly X that field, go back and add the field again and then search and repeat the whole process for each field. It's become extremely painful.

Some ten days back everything was fine. I have not installed any new software - only Windows 10 automatic updates have been installed.